# json_encode not showing anything in my external javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i got my php page which is fetchong an array from mysql i want to move that array to javascript with json_encode here is my php page

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript1.js'></script>";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT l_longitude,l_latitude FROM register_complain");



 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
  <th>Latitude</th>
 <th>Longitude</th>
 </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['l_longitude'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>
    " . $row['l_latitude'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo $ab = $row['l_latitude'];

    echo $ab2 = $row['l_longitude'];
     echo json_encode( $ab );
    echo "</table>";
 header('Location:http://localhost/cca/View_Map.html');  
mysqli_close($con);
```

and my external javascript1.js is

```
  var db_array = <?php echo json_encode($ab); ?>;
  alert(db_array);
```

but when i use that var db_array in my javascript page it dont shows alert message with values

Comment: is your console showing errors?

Comment: not showing any errors

Comment: what does your rendered javascript1.js file look like? And if the javascript file is separate from your php file how are you getting the `$ab` variable to it?

Comment: Wait you are using php to generate the js file right? you aren't actually just putting php code in a real .js file?

Comment: yes right i think thats the place where i am mistaking. my javascript file and my html file is seperate from my php page.

Comment: i am taking that variable $ab = $row['l_latitude']; to my seperate javascript .js file. i am new to php

Comment: yea just taking that line wont work as different php scripts do not share variables/data etc unless you save and read from like `$_SESSIONS` (which then you would need to learn how to use sessions in php) or save/read from files. So either put it all in one file, or put the processing in whatever scripts need it, or learn sessions to share data between scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in your php page first set $ab to value to javascript variable then include your js

```
echo "<script>var db_array = '". json_encode($ab)."';</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript1.js'></script>";
```

and alert in your js file

Comment: `json_encode` returns a json string which should when printed out directly in a javascript create a object/array literal. Your code would put it back as a string.

Comment: i have corrrected my code as you mentioned now it is showing me the alert message but the message is '<?php echo json_encode($ab); ?>' not the array which i have stored in $ab in my php page

Comment: @PatrickEvans i agree with you but need to js var from php file then include js file which we want to output

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a php script, put your javascript code in that and where you need the dynamic parts put your php code, or echo out your stuff there (processing should take place before outputting anything)

renderJS.php

```
<?php
    //code code code
    $data = someFunctionThatCreatesData();
    //more code code code
    //Makes it so browsers know this is actually a js file
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
?>
//Begin JS
var db_array = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
alert(db_array);
```

Then in your html point your script tag src to the php file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="renderJS.php"></script>
```

If your processing is in the same file as your html code then just do as Rakesh Sharma shows in his answer and output the `<script>` tag then your js code then the closing `</script>` tag within the same file (usually where you are echoing out your head tags)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a lot of similar stuff myself, but I do it the other way around. I tend to use jQuery so it would make my life much easier. Here is how I would generally do what you try to accomplish:

**The PHP script**

```
<?php
//...
//... get the database results into $result array
//...
// output results as JSON
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode($result);
exit();
```

**The Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$.getJSON('path/to/above/file.php', function(data) {        
    // alert(data) will only show [Object object]
    // as with the correct header set it will return
    // a Javascript Object/Array
    console.log(data);
});
```

When the Javascript code runs it will start an AJAX request to the PHP file and that will return the encoded data. I hope this helps.